# WPF TwoWay DataBound ComboBox from a DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I Currently have a XAML ComboBox inside a custom control.

```
<ComboBox Name="cboPropertyName"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          Visibility="Hidden"
          GotFocus="TxtPropertyName_GotFocus"          
          DataContextChanged="CboPropertyName_DataContextChanged"  
          SelectionChanged="CboPropertyName_SelectionChanged"/>
```

which is connected via Code Behind

```
        DataView DataPropsView = new DataView(_ControlData.Tables["GME_DataProperties"]);
        DataPropsView.RowFilter = "Key < 1000";
        DataPropsView.Sort = "Key ASC";

        cboPropertyName.DataContext = DataPropsView;
        cboPropertyName.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
        cboPropertyName.SelectedValuePath = "Key";

        cboPropertyName.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(_PropData["SubPropertyValue"]);
```

But when this customer control has the drop downlist changed the _PropData DataView never changes / Updates.

How can I make this be a TwoWay DataBinding so the DataView updates?

Comment: The way most people use a combobox is to inherit datacontext, bind the itemssource to a collection and the selectedvalue ( or index ) to a property in that inherited datacontext.  Often the items to select from are static data and a dynamicresource suits. A collection in the main viewmodel is a common choice.

Comment: Which row in `_PropData` do you want to update?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you abandon the codebehind and setup all the info in XAML to allow easier setup.

To use two-way binding on needs to bind the target to `SelectedValue` such as:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding CategoryID, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

---

You seem to have an issue with where the data resides which is really your greatest issue.

Generally one does not bind to a dictionary. Binding is in essence reflection and reflection into a dictionary is problematic to say the least. To do what you need to do, you should create a Notified property on the control and two-way bind to that. On the set for that property, change the dictionary value at the same time.

---

Also one does not bind to a view to change, because it is a view. Look into using a MVVM pattern, and create the view from the ViewModel, and bind your combobox to the viewmodel's data. Then the two-way binding will work as generally designed.